# D3 bubble chart - property map

Tags: javascript, c#, d3.js, bubble-chart

I am trying to use: 
https://github.com/UsabilityEtc/d3-country-bubble-chart

But I am having some problems when i try to draw:

[image]

I have copied the countries.csv and continent-names.json to local directory and it seems that I can read/load them correctly. But the drawing goes wrong. Here is some of my code and I have not changed anything in the script:

```
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "/countries.csv")
  .defer(d3.json, "/continent-names.json")
  .await(createBubbleChart);

function createBubbleChart(error, countries, continentNames)....
```

I dont quite get the "country" in:

```
var populations = countries.map(function (country) { return 
   +country.Population; });
```

Comment: I do not understand where "country" comes from. It is not a header in the .csv data. Dont quite get map.

Comment: you have to load them from a local web server, read the docs of `Array.map`